# losing react component ref after I Wrapped it by injectIntl

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an issue with getting the ref to the func in React components after I am wrapping it with injectIntl.
basically what I need is to get access to a func in the component by ref
here is what I am doing

```
class MainContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        }

    getSamples(){
      return sth
    }

   render() {
        return (<div>this.props.sth</div>)
        }

export default injectIntl(MainContainer )
```

it possible to get the ref to the MainContainer after wrapped it with injectIntl?

Comment: Are you trying to call a method of MainContainer? Your calling code would helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The withRef option should be passed.

```
export default injectIntl(MainContainer,{ withRef: true })
```

The MainContainer wrapper component instance can be retrieved using

```
<MainContainer ref={c => { this.container = c; }} />
```

The wrapped component instance can be retrieved using

```
this.container.getWrappedInstance();
```

Answer (score 4):

`injectIntl` has a `forwardRef` property which causes it to pass down `ref` to the wrapped component.

```
// MyComponent.jsx
// ...
export default injectIntl(MyComponent, {forwardRef: true});
// MyApp.js
import MyComponent from 'MyComponent';
class MyApp {
  render() {
    this.myComponentRef = React.createRef();
    return <MyComponent ref={ref} />;
  }
}
```

[reference](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/upgrade-guide-3x/#migrate-withref-to-forwardref)